# Extremely slow sql query when using multiple inner join and order clauses

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL database with three relevant tables, **t1** with **6598** rows, **t2** with **1713** rows and **t3** with **10023** rows.

Details:

```sql
TABLE t1 (
    `id` SERIAL,
    `t2_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `t3_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES t2(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (t3_id) REFERENCES t3(id)   
);

TABLE t2(
    `id` SERIAL,
    `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

TABLE t3 (
    `id` SERIAL,
    `name` VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I want perform the following query but it does not finish (takes forever basically):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t3
ON t1.t3_id = t3.id
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.t2_id = t2.id
WHERE (t3.name NOT NULL)
ORDER BY t3.name ASC , t1.id ASC
LIMIT 25
```

When i remove the order clause it works very fast (0.17 sec).

How could i change the query to make it work?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you *really* using? SQL Server doesn't use backticks (`\` `) for delimit identifying objects, so I suspect the former. Please retag your post appropriately.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is redundant since the column `t2.name` can never be null anyway, not according to the table definition. I would suggest studying up on indexes and query optimisation for MySQL.

Comment: @Larnu it is a MySQL server.

Comment: @e_i_pi i corrected this mistake, it was meant to be t3.name

Comment: Indexing the fields you use in order by could solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following indices:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t1 ON t1 (t2_id, t3_id, id);
CREATE INDEX idx_t3 ON t3 (id, name);
```

These indices at the very least should substantially speed up the joins.  If used, MySQL would most likely be taking the following joining strategy:

```
SELECT *
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1
    ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
INNER JOIN t3
    ON t1.t3_id = t3.id
WHERE
    t3.name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    t3.name,
    t1.id
LIMIT 25;
```

The idea here is that we do a full table scan on `t2`, which is by far the smallest table.  There are no restrictions on the records in `t2` anyway, so we might as well scan this first.  Then, for each of the joins to `t1` and `t3` we try to use the indices setup.  Note that because your tables have relatively few columns, the two indices defined can easily cover all columns, thereby increasing the likelihood that MySQL will choose to use the indices.

Comment: `t1.id` is useless, toss it.

Comment: @RickJames Are you saying that because InnoDB will automatically cover with the primary key column?

Comment: This should be the PK:  `(t2_id, t3_id)`.  See the link in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

`t1` is a many:many mapping table.  It does not need a surrogate `id` for the PK.  Instead it needs a composite PK of the two other columns,  Plus an index the other direction.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table for discussion of those and several other tips.